# Convergence of the Infinite Series of Reciprocals of Primes to 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

I am a junior high school student in Japan and I came up with an idea for something, but I don't know the name of it at all, even though I looked it up. Furthermore, I know only a little about high school math, and even less about English.
So please tell me a lot about the name of this series of proofs and so on. Also, please let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong or if there is anything that could be expressed better using high school math.

**The infinite series $\frac{1}{n}$ +($\frac{1}{2}$ (1-$\frac{1}{3}$)+$\frac{1}{3}$) (1-$\frac{1}{5}$)+$\frac{1}{5}$ ... converges to 1**(It could be established even if $\frac{1}{n}$ is excluded.)

~ ~ ~ ~

**1**

*Let ***n*** be the largest natural number. Then the number of natural numbers is also ***n***.*

(I had written "Let n be the largest natural number", which is incorrect, I was missing the very important knowledge that *"the greatest natural number does not exist."* I am really sorry.
Thanks so much **Xander Henderson**, **John Hughes**, **jjagmath** for replying.)

Then,
***n*** (number of natural numbers) = 1 + number of multiples of 2 + number of multiples of 3 without duplicates + number of multiples of 5 without duplicates + ... The equation is

**2**

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10... 1 in 2 Multiples of 2 => Number of multiples of 2 = $\frac{n}{2}$

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,... 1 in 3 Multiples of 3 => Number of multiples of 3 = $\frac{n}{3}$

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.... . 1 in 5 Multiples of 5 ⇒ Number of multiples of 5 = $\frac{n}{5}$ ....
. and so on.

However, we have to omit "$\frac{n}{2}$" and "$\frac{n}{3}$", because 6,12, etc. are duplicated.

Multiples of 3 ($\frac{n}{3}$) ⇒ 3,6,9,12 ... . 2 multiples of 3 come with one duplicate multiple of 2 => multiple of 3 without duplicate = $\frac{n}{3}$-$\frac{n}{3}$($\frac{1}{2}$)=$\frac{n}{3}$(1-1/2)

Multiples of 5 ($\frac{n}{5}$) ⇒ 5,10,15, ... . 1 in 2 multiples of 5 and 1 in 3 without duplicates Duplicate multiples of 2 and 3 come => Duplicate multiples of 5 without duplicates = $\frac{n}{5}$(1-$\frac{n}{2}$-$\frac{n}{3}$(1-$\frac{n}{2}$)).

**3**

Therefore, n=1+$\frac{n}{2}$+$\frac{n}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$)+$\frac{n}{5}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$-$\frac{1}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$))) .... This becomes.
And dividing both sides by ***n***,
1=$\frac{1}{n}$ +$\frac{1}{2}$+$\frac{1}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$)+$\frac{1}{5}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$-$\frac{1}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$)) .... which becomes

And $\frac{1}{2}$+$\frac{1}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$)+$\frac{1}{5}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$-$\frac{1}{3}$(1-$\frac{1}{2}$))... Generalizing the following,
1=$\frac{1}{n}$ +($\frac{1}{2}$ (1-$\frac{1}{3}$)+$\frac{1}{3}$) (1-$\frac{1}{5}$)+$\frac{1}{5}$ ... Then, we have

Thus, the infinite series "$\frac{1}{n}$ +($\frac{1}{2}$ (1-$\frac{1}{3}$)+$\frac{1}{3}$) (1-$\frac{1}{5}$)+$\frac{1}{5}$ ..." **"converges to 1"**.

(Thanks **Xander Henderson**, for letting me know about the MathJax tutorial.
However, I apologize for not being very familiar with this format and making it very esoteric.)

Comment: I am confused from your first statement.  You say that $n$ is the largest natural number.  But there is no largest natural number.  This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but suppose you say "n is some large natural number", do the analysis written here, and then think about the results as $n \to \infty$. That is how an experienced mathematician would probably approach the same ideas, even though perhaps they *thought* of them by saying "half of all integers are even; a third are multiples of 3 ..." as they were dozing off one night.

Comment: In addition, please take the time to read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) and work to format your mathematics in a way that is more readable.  Right now, it is very difficult to parse your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, there are some deep mistakes in your statements. For example, there is no such thing as "the largest natural number". Your idea, however is not wrong. We have $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{7}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\cdots = 1$$
Or in terms of mathematical notation $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{p}\prod_{\substack{q\text{ prime}\\q<p}}\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right) = 1$$

or equivalently $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$$
but a formal proof requires **much more** than what you did, since it's equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem which took more than a century and very advanced Mathematics to be proven.

Comment: It lacked very important knowledge. I am really sorry.
Thank you so much for replying to me. You have helped me solve what I wanted to know.

Comment: @jjagmath the way the terms $\pm 1/n$ come out in the 1st displayed series is not in increasing order of $n$ : $1/2$, $1/3$, $-1/6$, $1/5$, $-1/10$, $-1/15$, $1/30$, etc. So this sum is a rearrangement of the terms in $-\sum_{n \geq 2}\mu(n)/n$, and thus saying the two sums are equal involves comparing rearrangements of a nonabsolutely convergent series: that can be subtle.

Comment: @KCd I'm aware of that, but I didn't want to give more technical details, given the Mathematical level of the OP.